# bold and italic tag xml issue in flash with character embedding

Tags: flash

I am uploading text in flash as2 from xml and I need to do some text in bold, italic, underline and anchor. Text are visible fine and underline and anchor tags are working fine, but bold and italic tags are not working.

If I select character embedding to all then bold and italic tags are not working. If I select do not embed option then it's working fine. But, I have to use character embedding because I have to use text in all languages.

Comment: in your xml add bold<b>, italic<i> tags for your text (in CDATA block I assume), and use htmlText to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed the bold and italic fonts too (and Bold Italic).

Create separate, hidden textfields anywhere on your Flash movie and set their fonts as being the bold version, the italic version, and the bolditalic version. That ensures that the font will be embedded inside the movie.

TextFields can only embed one font at a time, hence why you need this trick.